# Ansible 'ERROR! Missing target hosts'

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get some very basic things working with Ansible 2.1.1.0 on OS X.

My targets are all Ubuntu 16.04, so the very first thing I have to do is get it to install python2.7, as without that even 'ping' won't work.

I have an inventory set up like this in `servers`:

```
[dbservers]
192.168.x.x set_hostname=db

[webservers]

[servers:children]
dbservers
webservers
```

And this is my play in `init.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: False
  become: yes
  tasks:
     - name: apt-get update
       raw: /usr/bin/apt-get update -qq
     - name: Install python 2.7
       raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || /usr/bin/apt-get install -q -y python2.7 python-simplejson
```

I check that it's selecting the right hosts by specifying the `dbservers` group, which is a subset of `servers` (there is only 1 anyway), which looks right to me:

```
# ansible dbservers -i servers --list-hosts
  hosts (1):
    192.168.x.x
```

The command I'm running is this:

```
# ansible dbservers -i servers init.yml
```

and that's when I get the error `ERROR! Missing target hosts`. I don't understand how it can have hosts and no hosts at the same time! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run a `playbook` with the `ansible` command. The `ansible` command is for `add-hoc` commands.

Try executing your playbook with `ansible-playbook` command:

```
ansible-playbook -i servers init.yml
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple! It didn't occur to me that these would be handled separately. I had been wondering how conflicts between CLI targets and `hosts` directives were resolved - and the answer is, they're not!

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong: You can do anything with `raw`, and installing the Python prerequisites is a very common thing to do with it.

Comment: You are right. It was even on the page I linked to. I deleted that paragraph. My fault.